# What does ‘all but finitely many $a_i$ are 0’ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading the definition of polynomials on page xxx of the book [https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-08693-4.pdf](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-08693-4) as shown in below. I am confused of the sentence *all but finitely many $a_i$ are 0*.

**Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring $R$. We define a polynomial over $R$ as a formal infinite sum**
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}=a_0+a_1\omega+a_1\omega^2+...,$$
**where $a_i\in R$ and all but finitely many $a_i$ are $0$.**

What does it mean? It on the one hand states **all**, then I think it means all of $a_1, a_2, …$ are zeros, so it should be **infinity**, which contradicts to **finitely many $a_i$** in the sentence.

Could anyone help to clarify this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey important information that is not present in the rest of the post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah ok, I will re-edited right now.

Comment: All of them are 0. *Except* a finite number of them, which may be nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, *all* but *finitely many* $a_i$'s are equal to $0$. For a very simple example, in the case of a polynomial of the form

$$ a_0 + a_1 \omega + a_2 \omega^2 $$

only finitely many $a_i$'s (where $i \in \{0, 1, 2\}$) are non-zero. All other $a_i$'s (namely, $i \in \mathbb{N}_0 \setminus \{0,  1, 2 \}$) are $0$'s. This is what is meant by a polynomial as defined in your post.

Another such polynomial may be $a_0 + a_2 \omega^2 + a_4 \omega^4$, etc., but the common point is that the *coefficients* (i.e., the non-zero $a_i$'s) are only finite in number.

Meanwhile, if an *infinite* number of $a_i$'s are non-zero, this is not a polynomial (nor perhaps an *algebraic* function) but may be a *transcendental* function (and thus, not a polynomial as defined above). Examples are functions you may encounter in calculus that may be expressed as the infinite sum (i.e., a series). Such examples are:

$$ f(x) = e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i, \quad \quad \text{where } a_i = \frac{1}{i!} $$

The below is a *rational function* (which is an algebraic function) but is not a polynomial:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i \quad \quad \text{where } a_i = 1 \text{ } \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_0 $$

More examples of *functions* which are non-polynomials include the trigonometric functions such as $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$, and logarithmic functions.

Thus, if $\not \exists$ finitely many non-zero $a_i$'s, then it is not considered a polynomial by definition.

*P.S. To clarify one thing - you may encounter in your study of algebra the concept of algebraic functions - functions that can be defined as the root of a polynomial equation. This is a fine distinction from a function being a polynomial, as algebraic functions are not necessarily polynomials themselves. Examples are functions such as the radical $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$, which is a radical function and is not a polynomial, but is nonetheless an algebraic function, as well as the example of a rational function given above, which is $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$.*

Answer (score 4):

It means there aren't infinitely many nonzero $a_i$: in fact, there might not be any.

Answer (score 4):

The statement "All but finitely many $a_i$ are zero" means that the set $\{i \mid a_i \ne 0\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there are some $a_i's$ that are not zero and the rest are zero.

Comment: Thanks. Then why the book states **all**?

Comment: The "all" means all other $a_j$'s are zero because a polynomial is viewed as a formal infinite sum with only some of the terms are non zero and the rest must be zero.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics notice the *but* that follows? Your problems seems to be with the English, not the mathematics. "All but x many" means everything minus x many.

Comment: The word "but" modifies the "all". Then "All ... but ..." means "everyone of these ... except"

Comment: This answer is wrong because (i) there might be no nonzero $a_i$ and (ii) your interpretation would allow for infinitely many nonzero $a_i$, and it shouldn't.

Comment: Second J.G.'s remark. The word "finite" matters a lot here, and it's not being used.